# 'Ours' meaning 'our home' - where is it used outside the UK, if anywhere?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, slang, word-usage

In expressions like:

> Let's go back to ours and have some food.
>   There's a party at ours on Friday.
>   There's a bottle of brandy at yours, isn't there?

'*ours*' and '*yours*' are synonyms for '*our/your home*' or '*our/your place*'. '*Mine*' can also be used in this way.

**Is this usage solely BrE or does it occur in other Englishes?**

Note: "I (don't) use/understand '*ours*' like this and I live in X" answers are welcome, but I'm really looking for hard data  such as corpus research, dictionary entries that mention this usage etc.

Comment: In all the cases above, "ours" refers to a occasion that is going to be hosted at your home. People usually use this in this when they want to refer to something that includes hosting by you and your family members. In the above case, it meant that the party is going be hosted by you and your members (cause they are also a part during organization of the whole party setup.)

Answer (score 3):

I didn't know of this usage of *ours* and *yours*, so to try and get some data I sifted through lists of hists in two corpora: the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) and the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/). I looked for “at ours”, “at yours”, “to ours”, and “to yours”. I went through the hits to check for context in each case. What I see is:

- There are a few results in the British corpus matching your described usage. All of them come from spoken sources (conversations recorded and transcribed), with no such hit from written sources (magazines, fiction or whatever). I would hazard a guess: maybe these few hits are all from a given geographical area or dialect, though I could not confirm it (could not find any detail on the sources in the BNC search interface).
- There is no such usage recorded in the American corpus, which would tend to indicate that it's indeed a regional usage.

That conclusion is not definitive, however, given the relatively low number (a dozen) of matching records in the BNC in the first place. (Absence of evidence not being evidence of absence, unless you have great statistics.) However, that's the best I can do.

Comment: Interesting. I'm wondering if expressions like "Let's go to **John's** (John's place)", (which I here often here in England) would also seem to be exclusively BrE.

Comment: Curious.  It's really rather common here to hear something like, "come round to ours for dinner tonight."

Comment: There are two instances of 'back to mine' in the BNC, both as direct speech.  This has phrase has a sexual connotation of course, and amusingly one of them is from a *Mills & Boon* novel.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of results in the [Corpus of Historical American English (COHA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/) but most provide context immediately before, e.g.:

> "We're always a party, darling, aren't
> we? You come to mine and I'll come to
> yours."
>
> Mary McMullen - 'Death by Bequest' (1977)

The query used to generate results was:

- WORD(S): to ours/yours/mine/theirs
- COLLOCATES: back/over/come
- FIELD 3: 4   <- COLLOCATES within 4 word(s) to the left of WORD(S)
- FIELD 4: 0   <- COLLOCATES within 0 word(s) to the left of WORD(S)

As @F'x notes above, such usage may be predominantly found in speech.

However there may still be scope to find additional written examples from this source given the number of possible combininations vs. the limited extent of the query above.

Comment: Of course, *ours* with its object implied (“Can you come at our place? — Well, why not coming to ours?”) is often found, in both written and spoken sources.

Answer (score 1):

Yet this use is almost unknown the U.S. We hear it in UK television. Particularly in programs from the North. E.g. Happy Valley and Scott and Bailey. 
Normal usage here is always with the noun attached. my house, my place. Also hear this in reference to siblings and parents. 
In U.S. Usage is my mother, not our mother, unless two children are present.

Comment: This matches my experience along the US east coast.

Answer (score 0):

I grew up in New Zealand and my family, who were from the south of England,
have always used possessive pronouns like this. So for me saying

1. Let’s go to yours.
2. She’s staying at mine.

is no different from saying

3. I bought it at the grocer’s.
4. I have to go to the doctor’s.

Comment: Hello, Nina. 'The grocer's / The doctor's ...' have been accepted deleted forms for a long time, as have 'at  Sainsbury’s / at Waterstone's (admittedly now without the apostrophe). The corresponding forms would be 'to your' / 'at my'.

Answer (score 0):

"Come to ours", "go to yours", "pop to John's", "go to my mum's", "a party at Mary's" all work in the same way as "going to the baker's". All widely used in the UK and definitely not a regional variant.

Comment: Can you add some references?

Comment: @ b.roth - today i serendipitously came across a reference as i was reading the chicago manual (2015). it mentions "dinner at the Browns' (that is, at the Browns' home)" exactly as quoted here  [7.18 proper nouns, letters and numbers]. that shows this usage is also accepted in the US.

Comment: @ edwin ashworth - i respectfully disagree. the forms  'to your' and 'at my', which you avow should correspond to the "accepted deleted forms" you mentioned (the grocer's, the doctor's), could never stand on their own. they are possessive adjectives and thus cannot be used by themselves. possessive pronouns, however, can and must appear alone, making them the perfect candidates for this usage... much in the same way i can look at a pair of shoes and say "those are mine" (rather than "those are my shoes"), i can refer to "my house" as simply "mine".

Comment: @ edwin ashworth - i know you know a lot more than i do about grammar and that you didn't need my mundane example. i added it for other people's sake . i wanted to have this be part of my comment above, but was running out of characters...  anyway, since i started a new comment, i'd like to use the opportunity to ask you how come you are not familiar with this usage being an Oldhamer. i've heard this construction plenty of times when i was up there...  or are you familiar with it , but you find it nonetheless unacceptable? thanks a lot

Comment: PS:a search in COCA  for "back to mine" shows 14 results (3 of which are definitely used in the sense  of 'back to my house'  -  2 of those can be axed due to mentioning apartment or house just before  "...let's leave this anonymous apartment, go back to mine and stay..."  and   "...in front of christine's house, and i  trudged back to mine..." , but 1 is valid  "...didn't think he should be alone so i took him back to mine..."). it seems that,  although uncommon, it is also used in the US...