# Is "my place" correct and common in British English?

Tags: idioms, word-usage, british-english

I was recently told that "my place", such as in "let's go to my place" is not commonly used in British English? Is that the case and what would you say instead?

Comment: No, it's common in British English. It's informal.

Comment: And probably still preferred to _mine_, _ours_ as in "let's go to mine", a US usage, I believe, which is catching on with many people over here. To my ears, none of the alternatives sounds exactly right (though they're grammatically acceptable) - but nicking the French _chez mois_ sounds even worse. Pretentious.

Comment: Even if the question were "Your place or mine?" I'm not sure I would respond with "Mine" or "Let's go to mine." I would say "my place" almost always. The only exception may be "Were you at your house or hers last night?" There I might just say "mine." I am using myself as a representative American for this survery, btw.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: as a USian (no, nobody really says that), I've never heard or would say "let's go to mine". All kinds of wrong. "mine?" Wait...I can think of one instance where that might work. 'Mine' needs a prior referent, so "Hey, do you want to go to my place" "No, let's go to mine" would work.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don’t know where “Let’s go to mine” is from, but it isn’t in America.

Comment: At http://www.regionplus.co.uk/2012/08/all-back-to-ours-as-preston-celebrates/ one finds: _The North West is inviting the country ‘back to ours’ to enjoy Preston Guild 2012._ There is already a thread covering this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28079/ours-meaning-our-home-where-is-it-used-outside-the-uk-if-anywhere . Apparently, it's more British than I would like, though there are some examples in COCA. It's certainly fairly common in speech hereabouts. Perhaps the expression was popularised by the series of _Back to Mine_ albums released by British electronica band _Faithless_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, for info the French would be _chez moi_ (without the 's'). To be even more pretentious but risk not to be understood, can try _à la maison_, meaning "at my place".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*My [place](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/place_1)* is simply an informal way of saying *my [home](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/home_1)* and is certainly used. To sound very formal, use *my [residence](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/residence)*.

Comment: "Let's go to my residence." "Your residence or my residence?" Yeah, works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply will-hunting, and @regdwigh, thanks for the laugh! I'll have a party at "my residence" to celebrate!

Comment: I'd qualify Will Hunting's response, and say that "my place" is an informal way of saying "the place where I currently live", and that a more formal alternative would have to be context-specific - "my house", "my flat", "my apartment", depending on the type of place in which you live. "My residence" is not just formal, it's pretty much archaic in anything other than technical language, or as a joke.

Comment: I agree with Berthilde. ‘My residence’ is so formal that I can’t imagine it ever being used! Maybe the queen would say it but I doubt it.  Instead ‘my house’ or ‘my flat’ is a bit more formal and polite than ‘my place’.

Answer (score 2):

The [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) includes 240 instances of *my place* and 104 of *our place*, and while they're not all directly relevant to this question, there's plenty of evidence that they're used in the relevant sense.

> Our place was badly flooded
>
> You could stay at our place if you want.
>
> Paddy ends up coming round to my place!
>
> She said' my place' as though it were some stately country house, though it was just...

etc.

Comment: It’s casual though. If talking about a party or casual invitation, then you can say ‘my place’. But if telling your boss your place is flooded - or inviting them to stay - you’d probably say ‘my house’. For some reason ‘place’ has a connotation of ‘casual things going on’ - parties, relaxation, So it’s only used in informal situations.

Comment: @Jelila, I'm not sure how you draw that conclusion from the BNC, where it's not especially easy to distinguish formal vs informal settings. But one example which is clearly a formal setting is [this one](//www.english-corpora.org/bnc/x4.asp?t=1723&ID=50505501), from a chaired meeting of (apparently) an engineering society.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're assuming where I draw my conclusions from. What is BNC?

Comment: I assumed that since you commented on my answer rather than the question, your comment was specific to my answer, and the only thing my answer discusses is the evidence from the British National Corpus (BNC).

Answer (score 1):

American here. I've had people catch me using **"mine"** and **"yours"** rather than "my place" or "your place."  I think I started saying it because it's faster to type. Maybe? Either way, I haven't run into anyone who didn't understand what I meant. However, my gf is a writer and studied english in school. When she brings it up that I say this, she mentions it's more of a British thing rather than an American thing.

Comment: Never heard it in this corner of the country, but then I'm not really into the social scene.