# Dinner at mine or yours?

Tags: british-english

I have noticed in British TV shows the common usage of 'mine' or 'yours' being used to mean 'my place' and 'your place' respectively. I spent a year in Britain in the early 1980s and I don't recall hearing this usage then.
When did it appear? Is it only a British or English thing?
What brought it to mind was when I heard it in Foyle's War which is set in the early 1950s. A possible anachronism?

Comment: I watch British TV shows all the time and I haven't heard it. Sometimes English speakers make up their own expression. Or if they have already been talking about their places, there is no need to repeat it.

Comment: It sounds perfectly normal and idiomatic to me, in Britain. Indeed adding *place* strikes me as American.  I don't think I would say *my place* or *our place* unless we lived in a twenty-seven bed stately home.

Comment: It sounds idiomatic to me _in the context of that opposition_. I'm not sure that I would find "You left it at mine" or "It's at yours" idiomatic. However "We went to John's" is normal for me.

Comment: By chance, I heard this usage on (UK) TV last night, and it caught my attention because the speaker was an RP-speaker, and I *thought* this usage was regional.  When I moved from East Yorkshire to Liverpool in 1970, I noticed Liverpool speakers saying things like, "I'll see you later at yours", and it was new to me.

Comment: I’ve heard it! From Liverpudlians back in about 1985. As in ‘Shall we go back to mine?’ Meaning ‘my place’. Or yours? Meaning ‘your place’. So perhaps it’s a regional thing. I had never heard that previously. I’m from London and I never heard it used by Londoners.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's an anachronism - I think it's relatively new.  This is an example of an omission-gap conflation and a retro-intrusion parallelization followed by a pronomial generalization. (No, ha-ha, not really - I just made that up because I can't remember the real name for what that process is called, but it happens all the time in language.)

The previous form we're used to is: "my place or yours".  But actually what's happening even here with "yours" is that "place" (digs, crib, cottage, castle, flat, house, whatever you want to name it) is already omitted.  What is implied is "my place or your place".  "Your place" conflates to just "yours".    This happens in language shift for many different reasons, like efficiency, intimacy, regionalism, etc.

In the example above, the more current form of "mine" is changed to parallel "yours":  the conflation of "yours" syntactically has a leftward influence and causes the same conflation of "my place" into "mine".

Then, the use of "mine" takes on its own meaningfulness and independence of usage, and as in David G's comment "we went back to mine..." Where the use of "mine" referring to "my place" no longer needs the context of "yours" or "your place".  It morphs into its own stand-alone from possessive pronoun liberated into full noun-ness.

In American usage, I've only heard it in colloquial phrases like, "Don't worry, I'll get mines."  Meaning, "I'll get what's owed to me."  The form "mines" includes a final "s" either because it parallels (or mimics, or experiences intrusion - I can't remember, and I can't find the term for it...sorry) the final "s" in "yours" or because "mine" has already become nounified and the "s" indicates the plural...

What would be cool to find out, if anyone knows, what forms or production of possessives in other languages (not English) may have been an influence in your different regions - and how human geography shifts the usage... or even better, we could ask Anthony Horowitz...

Comment: Here is a similar discussion about "my place" in British usage. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92464/is-my-place-correct-and-common-in-british-english

Comment: My comment about it being an anachronism was referring to it having been used in a show that was set around 1950, thus being before this usage seems to have appeared. I am surprised more people haven't heard it being used. I think your answer is pretty close to covering it but I won't accept it yet in the hope of getting more comments about when it started to appear and in which regions.

Comment: my bad - I misinterpreted anachronism:

1.a thing belonging or appropriate to a period other than that in which it exists, especially a thing that is conspicuously old-fashioned: 
"everything was as it would have appeared in centuries past apart from one anachronism, a bright yellow construction crane"

•an act of attributing a custom, event, or object to a period to which it does not belong.

Comment: ...and I will be checking out Foyle's War on PBS here in the states....now that Downton is over ; (

Comment: @BeaBonmot, please feel free to edit your answer to correct your original misinterpretation....

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having seen this described usage on TV, I am British and lived there most of my life so I'm familiar with English in many of its different forms across the UK (and further afield).

colloquially common.  I have rarely  heard "mine" or "yours" as synonyms or abbreviated phrases for "my place" or "your place" (respectively.  However, if I said to someone, "We can meet at the house" (s)he could legitimately ask "mine or yours?" or use either on it's own, either as a question "mine?" or as a statement "yours!".

I believe this is legitimately English but I'm not sure if it fits the circumstances that interest you or not.  To explain any better (if I even could), I would need to know the exact words said that caused the "mine" or "yours" response.

Comment: I agree that the usage you describe is perfectly valid English. What I have heard (many times now) is not as a response but as a statement. eg "After dinner we went back to mine to watch TV" "We could spend the night at yours then go to work"

Answer (score 0):

Born 1947 -  lived in Edinburgh, Aberdeen and London until 1974. Now Living in Denmark. About 20 years ago ‘come back to mine etc” popped up all over the place in books and on the tele. We never used that expression while I was in the UK. Always had a noun ‘house, place, flat etc’ No one here seems to have a valid explanation as to why the noun has been dropped. In French chez is accompanied by a pronoun ‘moi, toi etc’ Strange development.

Comment: When you accumulate enough reputation you will be able to leave comments such as this one. Have a look at the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how a good answer looks like.

Answer (score -1):

It wouldn't surprise me if this is accurate English because it reminds me of the French, "Chez moi ou chez toi", considering the influence French has on British English.

Comment: Yes but the French has the 'chez' meaning place. If the English was 'my place' it would sound normal to me, but the truncated 'yours' or 'mine' doesn't.